# Using code in init.py when running python from command line

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm setting up some code for unittesting. My directory currently looks like this:

```
project/
    src/
        __init__.py
        sources.py
    test/
        __init__.py
        sources_test.py
```

In __init__.py for the test directory, I have these two lines:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../')
```

In the test files, I have the line `import src.sources`.

When I use [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to run these tests from the project directory, everything works just fine. If I try to run the tests individually it gives me this error:

```
ImportError: No module named src.sources
```

I assume that this is because when I run the test from the command line it isn't using __init__.py. Is there a way I can make sure that it will use those lines even when I try to run the tests individually?

I could take the lines out of __init__.py and put them into my test files, but I'm trying to avoid doing that.

To run the tests individually I am running `python sources_test.py`

Comment: How are you running the tests "individually"?  What file are you running to do that?

Comment: I'm not using a file. The files have main methods in them

Comment: Are you in Python 2.x, or 3.x? In 2.x, you basically can't do what you want to do the way you want to do it. But there are some obvious workarounds: For example, just don't be inside the `test` directory.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.1

Comment: What do you mean you're "not using a file"?  When you say you "run the test from the command line", you must be running *something* from the command line.  What are you running from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really trying to abuse packages here, and that isn't a good idea.

The simple solution is to not run the tests from within the `tests` directory. Just cd up a level, then do `python tests/sources_test.py`.

Of course that in itself isn't going to import `test/__init__.py`. For that, you really need to import the package. So `python -m tests.sources_test` is probably a better idea… except, of course, that if your package is made to be run as a script but not to be imported, that won't work.

Alternatively, you could (on POSIX platforms, at least) do `PYTHONPATH=.. python sources_test.py` from within `tests`. This is a bit hacky, but it should work.

Or, better, combine the above, and, from outside of `tests`, do `PYTHONPATH=. python tests/sources_test.py`.

A really hacky workaround is to explicitly `import __init__`. This should basically work for you simple use case, but everything ends up wrong—in particular, you end up with a module named `__init__` instead of one named `test`, and of course your main module isn't named `test.sources_test`, and in fact there is no `test` package at all. Unless you accidentally re-import anything after modifying `sys.path`, in which case you may get duplicates of the modules.

Comment: I tried running it from outside the tests directory, but it still didn't work. If we could get that working that would be a good enough solution

Comment: "I tried… but it didn't work" doesn't help anything. Edit your question to show what you tried, and what it did wrong.

Comment: Running `python tests/sources_test.py` as you suggested gives me the same import error.

Comment: The `python -m...` trick works. Not as clean of a solution as I was hoping to be able to get, but it works.

Comment: @RobWatts: Actually, I think it's arguably cleaner. You can't run a script as part of a package; you have to instead do all kinds of hacky things to make it work. But running a _module_ as part of a package just works automatically. So, as long as your code actually runs as a module… what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

If you write

```
import src.source
```

the python interpreter looks into the src directory for a `__init__.py` file. If it exists, you can use the directory as a package name. If your are not in your project directory, which is the case when you are in the `src` directory, then python looks into the directories in `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable (at least in linux, windows should also have some environment variable, maybe with another name), if it can find some directory src with a `__init__.py` file in it.
Did you set your `$PYTHONPATH`?